# Where do I put a crossdomain XML in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, cross-domain, localhost, cross-domain-policy

I have a cross-domain policy file I wish to add to a Tomcat server I have.
If the tomcat is localhost:8080 and installed in /usr/local/tomcat/
Where would be that root folder where I should put this policy file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place your cross-domain policy into the `ROOT webapp` folder.

Check you can access it from

```
http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml
```