# Flash crossdomain.xml on Tomcat 8 at port 8080

Tags: tomcat8, flash, crossdomain.xml

On my local Tomcat 8 I added crossdomain.xml as explained here:

[Where do I put a crossdomain XML in Tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316668/where-do-i-put-a-crossdomain-xml-in-tomcat)

I did the check and I can see

```
http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml
```

from the browser.

But when I try to send a request from an `swf` in one of the web projects, it looks like it tries to find

```
http://localhost/crossdomain.xml
```

How do I tell Flash to search the file in the 8080 port?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml");
```

Also try to allow ports in crossdomain.xml itself

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
```

Comment: The first line: use where exactly...? Second line: already have it. Seems like the swf cannot find the file at this point, so how would it matter what I have there? If I understand how this security thing works, on the server side I am not supposed to do more than putting it in the domain root.

Comment: You need to add this first line right at the beginning of your flash project (as AS3 code). More on that here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#loadPolicyFile() . But normally you don't need a crossdomain on a localhost, it is only needed if you want to load something from another domain

Comment: @Philarmon Thanks. This was an `fla` that I did not originally create, but downloaded from the web. I had to change one of its associated `as` files, to point to my `localhost:8080` instead of some external domain. Then like you said I did not need `crossdomain.xml`.